# How to plot data from two data frames together as a stacked bar chart in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have two dataframes called `dbDateSubMSortNacional` and `dbDateSubMSortNacional`, which contain a series of dates and values of covid infections for males and females in a certain region for the corresponding dates. I have plotted them individually as

```
contagiosH=barplot(dbDateSubHSortNacional$total[1:5], names.arg = dbDateSubHSortNacional$fecha[1:5], cex.names=0.759, , cex.axis=1, main = "Masculino", xlab="Fechas yy-mm-dd" , ylab="Número de contagios", col = rainbow(5), border = "white", ylim=c(0, 5000))
text(contagiosH, dbDateSubHSortNacional$total[1:5], dbDateSubHSortNacional$total[1:5])

contagiosM=barplot(dbDateSubMSortNacional$total[1:5], names.arg = dbDateSubMSortNacional$fecha[1:5], cex.names=0.759, , cex.axis=1, main = "Femenino", xlab="Fechas yy-mm-dd" , ylab="Número de contagios", col = rainbow(5), border = "white", ylim=c(0, 5000))
text(contagiosM, dbDateSubMSortNacional$total[1:5], dbDateSubMSortNacional$total[1:5])
```

I was wondering if it were possible to plot them as the graph in the attached figure.
[image: Graph to be emulated]

I have managed to do it independently for a single dataframe called `datos`as

```
barplot(datos, beside=F, col=rainbow(5), legend.text = row.names(datos),
        args.legend=list(title ="RRSS preferidas", x="top", inset=c(0, -0.45)))
```

I have tried to merge both approaches as

```
barplot(dbDateSubMSortNacional$total[1:5], dbDateSubHSortNacional$total[1:5], names.arg = dbDateSubMSortNacional$fecha[1:5], cex.names=0.759, , cex.axis=1,  col = rainbow(5), border = "white", ylim=c(0, 4000))
```

Unfortunately, I get a single graph. Can someone please tell me how to achieve my goal?

EDIT: To generate a reproducible output, use

```
fecha <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07")
total <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13)

dbDateSubMSortNacional <- data.frame(fecha, total);

total <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)

dbDateSubHSortNacional <- data.frame(fecha, total);
```

Problem with the suggested solution by @jdobres:

[image: Problem]

Returns the error `Error in cbind(total.2022 - 1 - 10, total.2022 - 1 - 11, total.2022 -  :  object 'total.2022' not found` in

```
barplot(cbind(total.2022-01-10, total.2022-01-11, total.2022-01-04, total.2022-01-05, total.2022-01-12) ~ set, data = combined_wide, col = rainbow(5))
```

Comment: @Peter Please, tell me if the edit that I have done works for you

Comment: Thanks: should `redFav` be included in `datos`? And what is the connection between say `dbDateSubHSortNacional` and `datos`?

Comment: @Peter I am just posting the image so the issue can be seen The problem is the syntax. In, at least my computer, R does not recognize the symbol `-` as par of the name of the dataframe.

Comment: OK now I understand, it would be better if the reproducible dataset was a reflection of your actual data so the question represents your actual problem: should `fecha` be `c("2022-01-10","2022-01-11","2022-01-04",...)` rather than `c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",...`

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the suggestion. I have implemented the suggested change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` and `ggplot` solution, followed by a base R barplot option:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


df1 <- bind_rows(dbDateSubHSortNacional, dbDateSubMSortNacional)

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_col(aes(x = set, y = total, fill = fecha))
```

[image]

```r
#get data into wide format:

df2 <-
  df1 |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = fecha, values_from = total)


barplot(cbind(`2022-01-10`, `2022-01-11`, `2022-01-04`,`2022-01-05`, `2022-01-12`, `2022-01-17`, `2021-12-19`)~set, 
        data = df2 , 
        xlim = c(0,1),
        width = 0.30,
        col = rainbow(7),
        xlab = "Sex",
        ylab = "Frequency",
        legend.text = colnames(df2)[-1],
        args.legend = list(x = "topright"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

data

```
fecha <- c("2022-01-10","2022-01-11","2022-01-04","2022-01-05", "2022-01-12","2022-01-17", "2021-12-19")
total <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13)

dbDateSubMSortNacional <- data.frame(fecha, total)

total <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)

dbDateSubHSortNacional <- data.frame(fecha, total);

dbDateSubHSortNacional$set <- 'H'
dbDateSubMSortNacional$set <- 'M'
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to combine your two data frames into one:

```
dbDateSubHSortNacional$set <- 'H'
dbDateSubMSortNacional$set <- 'M'
combined <- rbind(dbDateSubHSortNacional, dbDateSubMSortNacional)

       fecha total set
1     Monday     2   H
2    Tuesday     4   H
3  Wendesday     6   H
4  Thuersday     8   H
5     Friday    10   H
6   Saturday    12   H
7     Sunday    14   H
8     Monday     1   M
9    Tuesday     3   M
10 Wendesday     5   M
11 Thuersday     7   M
12    Friday     9   M
13  Saturday    11   M
14    Sunday    13   M
```

If you want to plot this data with `barplot`, it would be easier to first `reshape` the data to "wide" format:

```
combined_wide <- reshape(combined, direction = 'wide', idvar = 'set', timevar = 'fecha')

  set total.Monday total.Tuesday total.Wendesday total.Thuersday total.Friday total.Saturday total.Sunday
1   H            2             4               6               8           10             12           14
8   M            1             3               5               7            9             11           13
```

And then the `barplot` command becomes:

```
barplot(cbind(total.Monday, total.Tuesday, total.Wendesday, total.Thuersday, total.Friday) ~ set, data = combined_wide, col = rainbow(5))
```

[image]

You could also use **ggplot2** to create a similar plot, without having to widen the data set:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = subset(combined, !(fecha %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday'))), aes(x = set, y = total, fill = fecha)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a pproblem, in my original data, the dataframe has names defined as yyyy-mm-dd, so, I have to write `barplot(cbind(total.2022-01-10, total.2022-01-11, total.2022-01-04, total.2022-01-05, total.2022-01-12) ~ set, data = combined_wide, col = rainbow(5))` to arrive to the plot, and I am getting the error: `Error in cbind(total.2022 - 1 - 10, total.2022 - 1 - 11, total.2022 -  : 
  object 'total.2022' not found`. I will attach an screenshot on the question hoping that you can help me again.